# cmd script with sqlplus not returning any results

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sqlplus

I a cmd script that looks like this right now:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('sqlplus user/pass@OMP1 @CheckRowCount.SQL') do set rowcount=%%a
if %ROWCOUNT% GTR 0 (
c:\Autobatch\Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ClientJobSender.exe     http://server/spotfireautomation/JobExecutor.asmx c:\AutoBatch\backup\Trigger_Test.xml
)EXIT
```

I know that the

```
'sqlplus user/pass@omp1 @checkrowcount.sql'
```

works because when I run that separately, I do get a rowcount back in sqlplus.

The

```
c:\Autobatch\Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ClientJobSender.exe     http://server/spotfireautomation/JobExecutor.asmx c:\AutoBatch\backup\Trigger_Test.xml
```

also works as well when run separately in CMD as well.

What I want to do is if the sqlplus command returns a rowcount of > 0, the run the other command. else exit...can't seem to string it together all together to work.

Comment: What is the issue? Do you get an error message or unexpected result?

Answer (score 0):

Add the two top lines from the code snippet and see what %rowcount% is being set to.

```
echo "%ROWCOUNT%"
pause
if %ROWCOUNT% GTR 0 (
```

You might find that your sqlplus command is returning a blank line at the end and rowcount is being set to nothing.  In that case then this should work:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('sqlplus user/pass@OMP1 @CheckRowCount.SQL ^|findstr "[0-9]" ') do set rowcount=%%a
```